# Merge 2 arrays into 1 multidimensional array by index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Been racking my brain for a few hours trying to merge these 2 arrays into 1 multidimensional array.

Here is the data, the output I want and what I've tried.

```
Array 1:

array (size=67)
0 => string '1/10/2015' (length=9)
1 => string '1/12/2015' (length=9)
2 => string '1/17/2015' (length=9)
3 => string '1/19/2015' (length=9)
4 => string '1/21/2015' (length=9)

Array 2:

array (size=67)
0 => int 3
1 => int 3
2 => int 3
3 => int 1
4 => int 4
```

Desired Multidimensional array:

```
array (size=67)
0 => 
  array (size=1)
   0 => int 3
   1 => string '1/10/2015' 
1 => 
array (size=1)
  0 => int 3
  1 => string '1/12/2015' 
2 => 
 array (size=1)
  0 => int 3
  1 => string '1/17/2015'
3 => 
 array (size=1)
  0 => int 1
  1 => string '1/19/2015'
4 => 
 array (size=1)
  0 => int 4
  1 => string '1/21/2015'
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$dailytotal = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);

$dailytotal = array_merge_recursive($arr1,$arr2);

$dailytotal = array_combine($arr1,$arr2);
```

And about 4 other different functions... can someone please put me in the right direction. My head is about to explode. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
array_map(null, $array2, $array1)
```

See http://php.net/array_map, the example with the `null` callback.